# Event dispatch in Magento before redirect

Tags: php, session, magento, redirect

I'm running into an issue when using event dispatch in Magento.

I'm using controller_action_predispatch to set a frontend session variable from a parameter in the URL.

Now, the issue seems like, when the user comes to the site initially, they might lend on a page that will redirect them to base URL (such a example.com to www.example.com).
But for some reason, after redirect, the session variable is lost...

Any ideas?

Thank you.

EDIT:

adding the code used:

```
public function grabRef($observer) {
    $ref = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('ref', $default);
    if (isset($ref) && !is_null($ref) and !empty($ref)) {

        Mage::getSingleton('core/session',array('name'=>'frontend'))->setRefid($ref);

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to add you current code of how you are setting the session.

Comment: FYI: Don't backtick code samples on StackOverflow.  The editor here is markdown based, so just indent your code samples with four characters and it'll be formatted as code.

Comment: Thanks, had a bit of an issue with the <code> thing... :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are only two remotely useful events dispatched prior to this redirection, but they are not specific to the redirect:

- `controller_front_init_before`
- `controller_front_init_routers`

The redirect depends on the "Auto-redirect to Base URL" setting from **System > Configuration > Web > Url Options**, which is evaluated by [`Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->_checkBaseUrl()`](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php#L300). This redirect occurs before any dispatching takes place, and it does not append GET or POST data, hence the loss of the param you are trying to capture.

Normally sessions are initialized under `adminhtml` or `frontend` session namespace based on the controller class being used (ref the action controller superclass method [`Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()`](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php#L494). You should be able to move your observer configuration under `global/events/controller_front_init_before`. ***Note that you must do this in the `global` event area, as the frontend event configuration part does not load until after this event is dispatched.*** That particular scenario cost me an hour once!

Comment: Thanks for the clear info.
Will the session be reset due to the url change?

Comment: For the scope you've defined, I think that you will not see session reset behavior.